# split strings that contain more than one substring

Tags: python, string, split, substring

I have a list of strings `names`

`names = ['Acquaintance Muller', 'Vice president Johnson Affiliate Peterson Acquaintance Dr. Rose']`

I want to split the strings that contain **more than one** of the following substrings:

`substrings = ['Vice president', 'Affiliate', 'Acquaintance']`

More precicely, i want to split **after the last character of the word that follows the substring**

`desired_output = ['Acquaintance Muller', 'Vice president Johnson', 'Affiliate Peterson', 'Acquaintance Dr. Rose']`

I dont know how to implement 'more than one' condition into my code:

```
names = ['Acquaintance Muller', 'Vice president Johnson Affiliate Peterson Acquaintance Dr. Rose']
substrings = re.compile(r'Vice\spresident|Affiliate|Acquaintance')
    splitted = []
    for i in names:
        if substrings in i:
            splitted.append([])
        splitted[-1].append(item)
```

Exception: when that last character is a point (e.g. `Prof.`), split after the **second** word following the substring.

---

**update:** `names` is more complex than i thought and follows

1. the title-like-pattern already answered correctly (`'Vice president Johnson Affiliate Peterson Acquaintance Dr. Rose'`)
2. until a second pattern of strings follows (`'Mister Kelly, AWS'`)
3. until a third pattern of strings follows until the end (`'Dr. Birker, Secretary Dr. Dews, Member Miss Berg, Secretary for Relations Dr. Jakob, Secretary'`)

`names = ['Acquaintance Muller', 'Vice president Johnson Affiliate Peterson Acquaintance Dr. Rose', 'Vice president Dr. John Mister Schmid, PRT Miss Robertson, FDU', 'Mister Kelly, AWS', 'Dr. Birker, Secretary Dr. Dews, Member Miss Berg, Secretary for Relations Dr. Jakob, Secretary']`

Sometimes `Secretary` is followed by varying specifications. I dont care about these characters that sometimes follow `Secretary` until the next name occurs. They can be dropped. Of course `'Secretary'` should be stored like in `updated_output`.

I created a - hopefully exhaustive - list `specifications` of the stuff that follows `Secretary`. Here is a representation of list:
`specifications = ['', ' of State', ' for Relations', ' for the Interior', ' for the Environment']`

**updated question**: how can i account for the third pattern using the `specification` list?

`updated_output = ['Acquaintance Muller', 'Vice president Johnson', 'Affiliate Peterson', 'Acquaintance Dr. Rose', 'Vice president Dr. John', 'Mister Schmid, PRT', 'Miss Robertson, FDU', 'Mister Kelly, AWS', 'Dr. Birker, Secretary of State', 'Dr. Dews, Member', 'Miss Berg, Secretary for Relations, 'Dr. Jakob, Secretary']`

Comment: The second part is impossible without making rules about how to process the "varying specifications" of things that can follow `Secretary`. Can you add some info about how to do that?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this :) I agree that there is no workaround the varying specification. That is why i manually created a list `specifications` of the characters that follow `Secretary`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import re

names = [
    "acquaintance Muller",
    "Vice president Johnson affiliate Peterson acquaintance Dr. Rose",
]
substrings = ["Vice president", "affiliate", "acquaintance"]

r = re.compile("|".join(map(re.escape, substrings)))

out = []
for n in names:
    starts = [i.start() for i in r.finditer(n)]

    if not starts:
        out.append(n)
        continue

    if starts[0] != 0:
        starts = [0, *starts]

    starts.append(len(n))
    for a, b in zip(starts, starts[1::]):
        out.append(n[a:b])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
['acquaintance Muller', 'Vice president Johnson ', 'affiliate Peterson ', 'acquaintance Dr. Rose']
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to split at the *word boundary* just before one of those three titles, so you can look for a word boundary `\b` followed by a positive lookahead `(?=...)` for one of those titles:

```
>>> s = 'Vice president Johnson affiliate Peterson acquaintance Dr. Rose'
>>> v = re.split(r"\b(?=Vice president|affiliate|acquaintance)", s, flags=re.I)
    ['', 'Vice president Johnson ', 'affiliate Peterson ', 'acquaintance Dr. Rose']
```

Then, you can trim and discard the empty results:

```
>>> v = [x for i in v if (x := i.strip())]
    ['Vice president Johnson', 'affiliate Peterson', 'acquaintance Dr. Rose']
```

---

With a list of input strings, simply apply this treatment to all of them:

```
def get_names(s):
    v = re.split(r"\b(?=Vice president|affiliate|acquaintance)", s, flags=re.I)
    return [x for i in v if (x := i.strip())]


names = ['Acquaintance Muller', 'Vice president Johnson Affiliate Peterson Acquaintance Dr. Rose']

output = []
for n in names:
    output.extend(get_names(n))
```

Which gives:

```
output = ['Acquaintance Muller',
 'Vice president Johnson',
 'Affiliate Peterson',
 'Acquaintance Dr. Rose']
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! Input is list, not string though :)

Comment: @id345678 that is not a big deal though. You know how to do this for one string, so you can loop over the strings in your list and apply the same treatment to each of them.